# set AlternatingRowStyle ,HeaderStyle ,RowStyle of gridview in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

In design page we can set AlternatingRowStyle ,HeaderStyle ,RowStyle ..etc css properties of a gridview like

```
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrowstyle" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="rowstyle" />
```

i am only able to set css properties for dynamically generated gridview in code behind page by `gv.CssClass = "tablestyle";`.But how can i apply css for AlternatingRowStyle ,HeaderStyle ,RowStyle properties for dynamically generated gridview??

Thanx

Comment: You could use Theme either , It's quiet simple and effective

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the very same way:

```
gv.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = "altrowstyle";
gv.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "headerstyle";
gv.RowStyle.CssClass = "rowstyle";
```

Comment: oh that was so easy..i didn't see that..i was assuming i can set css by `gv.AlternatingRowStyle="Cssclass"`..thanx for quick response

Comment: I was also doing the same thing @BibekGautam. So addicted to Stackoverflow which makes me feel "Stupid Me!!" :(.